# SpamAssassin: block e-mails from all-but-some domains to a specific user

Tags: email, spam

I have an e-mail address like so:

```
example@mail.com
```

I want SpamAssassin to block all mail to only this user except from domains `mail.com` and `mail.net`. All I've seen in the documentation are separate blacklist and whitelist rules, but how to combine them to create a combined rule?